# Incorrect domain for an URL in a Twig template using command

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-routing

In my Symfony2 project, I send email with a link to connect to my website, like

```
<a href="{{ url('login') }}">LOGIN</a>
```

When I use this template in a controller, the link is good.

```
<a href="https://example.com/login">LOGIN</a>
```

But if I use this template for my mail in a `ContainerAwareCommand` with a cron, it looks like

```
<a href="http://localhost/login">LOGIN</a>
```

It's not good. How am I suppose to do to make it work ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should Configure the Request Context Globally, as described in the doc [How to Generate URLs from the Console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html):

> you can redefine the parameters it uses as default values to change
>   the default host (localhost) and scheme (http). You can also configure
>   the base path if Symfony is not running in the root directory.
>
> Note that this does not impact URLs generated via normal web requests,
>   since those will override the defaults.
>
> ```
> # app/config/parameters.yml
> parameters:
>     router.request_context.host: example.org
>     router.request_context.scheme: https
>     router.request_context.base_url: my/path
> ```

hope this help